# How to do this query in firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Suppose I have a collection of documents, each document has two fields(A and B) of type number.
I want to query documents the satisfy this equation: A + B = 5;

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with just those two fields.  Firestore does not offer any sort of aggregate queries like this.  Your only real alternative is to store another field in the document that has the precomputed sum of A and B, then query that other field for equality with the sum you're looking for.

Comment: OK, fine but I want to understand what kind of sacrifice are they making here, why not providing a built-in query method to do that since I think it's really common that you will want to do that.

Comment: I mean if the issue with implementing this feature has something to do with indexing the fields, they probably could provide a special type of index that that is associated with a hidden field that holds this aggregation. Maybe something else other than that, they can definitely figure it out.

Comment: Firestore is designed to scale massively with billions of documents in a collection.  If it had to scan every document to add up each number, that would be extremely expensive and not scale well.  So it doesn't allow those queries, or any sort of query that requires a scan of all documents.  It has to be able to use a index to find documents.  That's why I'm recommending that you store a precomputed field - that will be indexed, and the query will work.

Comment: I am talking about fields from the same document. whenever the document is changed, the field that holds the aggregation will change. Just one extra write. I could implement a could function that does this, but I am talking about a more general way using a newly introduced index type and probably introducing hidden fields.

Comment: That's highly unlikely to ever happen (trust me, I used to be on the Firebase team).  You'll have to store the extra field with the sum of the two other fields and keep it up to date.  This is common for nosql type databases like Firestore.

Comment: I wanted to file a feature request but I think they definitely must be aware of this feature. anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: Feel free to file anyway.  Just don't expect a fast turnaround.